# Flutter Dart: Allign Row Widgets at bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am new to Flutter, I am trying to show two buttons in a row at the bottom,
I have tried all possible solutions, including Align, Expanded etc but it didn't work..
Please if someone can help, as my buttons don't go at the bottom of screen
Here's my code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
           //code
          ),
          Container(
            //code
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Intro()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Intro()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the layout you want in your row?

Comment: Kindly attach a code with parent widget.

Comment: @Hemal Done please check!

Comment: @BLKKKBVSIK I want my two buttons displaying at bottom of my screen or just a bit top from bottom

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code, Please check

```
Scaffold(
          body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      //code
                      ),
                  Container(
                      //code
                      ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Register',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Intro()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Register',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Intro()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ),
```

**OR**

You can use `bottomSheet` method of scaffold

```
Scaffold(
          bottomSheet: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Intro()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 50),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Intro()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      //code
                      ),
                  Container(
                      //code
                      ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: If you want to make this two button persistence then I think instead fo above you have to user `bottomSheet` widget of scaffold.

Comment: You have added a Column on top with MainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween, how is it going to push the row at the bottom?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please check. Both gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution involving the `bottomNavigationBar` property of the `Scaffold` widget where you can put any `Widget?` (here, we're using your `Row`):

You can play around with the provided code [on this dartpad.](https://dartpad.dev/ee1a35d92f151bdb8463be86729a0831?null_safety=true)

Here's the result:

[image]

```dart
return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 100, height: 80),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blue.shade900,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
              //code
              ),
          Container(
              //code
              ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The row will match its childrens height so because all buttons have the same height your final row is 80 (px) in height and therefore it doesnt matter where to align buttons. You can wrap your row in a container with color to see it.

The corruct solution would be to give the row height by wrapping it in a diffrent widget (like column) and stretch it to available space. Then inside the row you just need `CrossAxisAlignment.end`. But this depends on your layout.

For example:

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      row: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
         /* Buttons here **/
      ]),
    )

  ]
)
```

You can also refer to [the flutter layout guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) and [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as it almost translates 1-1 to flutter and

Comment: It didn't work, please check my code as I added parent widgets